# import conflict error and view to object error in eclipse

Tags: java, android

```
package com.invictus.blocks.controller;


import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Above imports are the two imports that conflict with each other and the coding of another error is shown below:

```
private View makeButton(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String paramString4)
{
Object localObject1;
if ((paramString1 == null) || (paramString3 == null))
{
  localObject1 = null;
  label11: return localObject1;
}
Object localObject2;
if (paramString2 == null)
{
  localObject1 = new Button(getContext());
  ((Button)localObject1).setText(paramString4);
  localObject2 = localObject1;
}
while (true)
{
  localObject1 = FilenameAndUrlConstants.makeUrl(paramString3, paramString1);
  ((View)localObject2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickLaunchInternalWebBrowser(getActivity(), (String)localObject1, getDef().getName()));
localObject1 = localObject2;
  break label11;
  localObject1 = getDef();
  ImageView localImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
  localImageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
  try
  {
    localObject2 = BlocksImageUtil.getImage(getTourDb().getPopulator(), paramString2, paramString3, ((Summary)localObject1).getBtnHeight(), 
  ((Summary)localObject1).getBtnWidth(), ((Summary)localObject1).getLoad());
    if (localObject2 != null)
    {
      localImageView.setImageDrawable(DrawableCreatorUtil.addHighAlphaRedSelector(new BitmapDrawable((Bitmap)localObject2), ((Summary)localObject1).getBtnWidth(),((Summary)localObject1).getBtnHeight()));
      localImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
    localObject2 = localImageView;
  }
  catch (InvictusDataException localInvictusDataException)
  {
    localObject1 = new Button(getContext());
    ((Button)localObject1).setText(paramString4);
    localObject2 = localObject1;
  }
}
}
```

In the above coding I'm getting two errors, one is import conflict and the other is for localObject1. If I remove any of the imports then more number of errors occur.
So can anyone please rectify this code?
NOTE: I'm using eclipse for coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer one LayoutParams with full qualified name, e.g., android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams . In this way, a variable typed LayoutParams is under type android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams .

I do not put your code in Eclipse, so I am not sure where the localObject1 make errors. But it is never a good choice to cast one object instance to various type.